# mysql join two table with MAX(value)

Tags: mysql, join

I have this mysql code witch is working very well

```
SELECT uid , MAX(value) AS bidvalue FROM auction 
WHERE pid = '$pid' and max_bid=0 
GROUP BY uid 
ORDER BY bidvalue DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

How can I join this selection with users table ON users.id=auction.uid?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use join for that your query might look like

```
SELECT uid, users.name, MAX(value) AS bidvalue
FROM auction 
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = auction.uid
WHERE pid = '$pid' and max_bid=0 
GROUP BY uid 
ORDER BY bidvalue DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

or

```
SELECT uid, users.name, MAX(value) AS bidvalue
FROM auction 
OUTER JOIN users ON users.id = auction.uid
WHERE pid = '$pid' and max_bid=0 
GROUP BY uid 
ORDER BY bidvalue DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

[with the joins details as per your need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any magic here:

```
SELECT uid, users.name, MAX(value) AS bidvalue
FROM auction 
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = auction.uid
WHERE pid = '$pid' and max_bid=0 
GROUP BY uid 
ORDER BY bidvalue DESC 
LIMIT 1
```